# OleDB lock duplication .NET MS Access

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

We are in the process of migrating away from MS Access to a modern DBMS, but in the mean time I have come across an issue to which I can not find a solution or explanation.

Typically, opening an OleDBConnection produces a lock file which hangs around for 1 minute after the last connection in the pool closes. If you examine this file it gives a bit of info on the locking process, etc. Usually (in all other parts of our code), this produces just one entry in the lock file regardless of how many times connections are opened and closed on the same process, great.

I have developed some new functionality using the exact same connection string which seems to build-up a new entry in this lock file for each connection.open(). I have made quite sure that all resources are closed in the finally block of each method. What is worse is that if I reload the page it produces an additional set until you reach the hard limit of 255 open connections/locks.

The only difference I can see in this and many other areas is that I load sub-objects before getting to the finally block. The following pattern continues down about 3 levels. I am loading a template to construct a data-entry form, so I am not terribly concerned about efficiency.

Has anyone ever come across this build-up of identical entries in their ldb/laccdb files?
Thanks

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='...\db.accdb';Persist Security Info=False;OLE DB Services=-1;
...
Public Overrides Function load(ByVal DB_ID As Integer) As Boolean
        Dim connection As OleDbConnection
        connection = New OleDbConnection(connStr)
        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = Nothing
        Try
            Dim loadCMD As New OleDbCommand(String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE ID = @db_ID", tableName), connection)
            loadCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@db_ID", DB_ID)
            connection.Open()
            reader = loadCMD.ExecuteReader()
            If reader.Read() Then
                ID = GetNullSafeValue(reader(Schema.FormSections.ID), GetType(Integer), failure)
                FormID = GetNullSafeValue(reader(Schema.FormSections.FormID), GetType(Integer), failure)
                SectionTitle = GetNullSafeValue(reader(Schema.FormSections.SectionTitle), GetType(String))
                Expanded = GetNullSafeValue(reader(Schema.FormSections.Expanded), GetType(Boolean))
                ServiceURL = GetNullSafeValue(reader(Schema.FormSections.ServiceURL), GetType(String))
                SectionOrder = GetNullSafeValue(reader(Schema.FormSections.SectionOrder), GetType(Integer), failure)
                Rows = FormRow.loadAllForSection(ID, config)
                Return True
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ExceptionHandler(ex, config)
        Finally
            If reader IsNot Nothing Then
                reader.Close()
            End If
            connection.Close()
        End Try
        Return False
    End Function
...
Public Shared Function loadAllForSection(ByVal db_SectionID As Integer, ByVal cfg As ReportManagerConfiguration) As List(Of FormRow)
    Dim retList As New List(Of FormRow)
    Dim connection As OleDbConnection
    connection = New OleDbConnection(cfg.RM_LabConfig.connString)
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = Nothing
    Try
        Dim loadAll As New OleDbCommand(String.Format("SELECT ID FROM {0} WHERE SectionID = @db_sID ORDER BY RowNumber ASC", cfg.RM_LabConfig.FormRowsTable), connection)
        loadAll.Parameters.AddWithValue("@db_sID", db_SectionID)
        connection.Open()
        reader = loadAll.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read
            Dim thisRow As New FormRow(cfg)
            thisRow.load(GetNullSafeValue(reader(Schema.FormRows.ID), GetType(Integer), failure))
            If thisRow.ID <> failure Then
                retList.Add(thisRow)
            End If
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        ExceptionHandler(ex, cfg)
    Finally
        If reader IsNot Nothing Then
            reader.Close()
        End If
        connection.Close()
    End Try
    Return retList
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From experimentation I have been able to determine that the lock build-up was caused by creating new connections inside other function calls before the outer calls released the connections.

The solution was to rewrite it in a way that ensured the connection was closed before going down into the lower levels.

The only thing this does not explain is why rerunning the query would build the list even further. The connections were closed eventually, so I would have expected it to use these slots the next time around.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this but I am trying to answer your question.

Try to close the connection in your Try Block and In finally block check if connection is already open. If already open then close it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this does not seem to have an effect.